# SQL get count(x) from y where theres a specific x

Tags: sql

How do I achieve a view in SQL for this? I want to get the number of books that exist in the shelf where book 2 is located. '2' is the book ID, and the book also has a shelf_id attributed to it. How do I find what shelf id it is and then search for how many books there are in it?

```
    SELECT COUNT(b.book_id)
    FROM book b, shelf s
```

I've tried a few things but am really not sure how to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

If `BOOK` table already has `shelf_id` attribute, then the following query would return you the number of books in the same shelf as `book 2`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books
WHERE shelf_id = (SELECT shelf_id FROM books WHERE book_id = 2)
```

This count include the `book 2` as well, btw. The procedure definition for SQL Server would be as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_count_of_books_in_shelf_by_book_id
(
    @book_id INT
)
AS
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books
    WHERE shelf_id = (SELECT shelf_id FROM books WHERE book_id = @book_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) it does work indeed, any help on how I could turn this into a procedure that would allow the user to introduce the desired Book ID instead of it being the default '2'?

Comment: Not sure what your DBMS is, but the updated answer has the procedure definition for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT COUNT(b2.*)
    FROM book b1 JOIN book b2
         ON b1.shelf_id = b2.shelf_id
     where b1.book_id = 2;
```

or

```
    SELECT COUNT(b2.*)
    FROM book b2 
    where b2.shelf_id in (select shelf_id from book b1 where b1.book_id = 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.book_id)
FROM book b 
INNER JOIN (SELECT s.shelf_id FROM book b1, shelf s WHERE b1.shelf_id = s.shelf_id AND b1.book_id = 2) j ON b.shelf_id = j.shelf_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had done something of the kind before but I was doing something wrong, I just had to modify little bits in your code and it works perfectly. Could anyone point me out how to turn this into a procedure where the user can input the desired ID? (Instead of it being the default '2')